# Error in compilation. what will be the correct code and output?

Tags: c++, c++11

why is there a compilation error(lvalue required in line 3)

what will be the correct code and then the output?

```
 #include<iostream>
 #define PRINT(i,LIMIT) \
  do{   if(i++<LIMIT)\
       { cout<<"Gradeup";\
         continue;  }\
         }\
       while(1)

using namespace std;


int main() {  

PRINT(0,3);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i++` and in your case `i` is replaced by `0`.

Comment: `if(i++<LIMIT)` expands to `if(0++<3)`. `0` is not an lvalue.

Comment: Expand the macro, see it after the preprocessing stage (always good when you have problems involving macros), and you will understand what's happening. And remember, the preprocessor and its macros are *not* the same as functions, and arguments to macros are not variables.

Comment: So there is no way where I could see the output here?

Comment: use this awesome tool: https://godbolt.org/ and `-E` to see output of preprocessor... and dont try to use macros in place of functions for the sake of your own mental health

Comment: This is an actual mcq question so I wanna know the output.

Comment: not clear what you want, the code does not compile, so there is no output

Comment: If you want to know the output, then turn `PRINT` into a *function* that you call, then build it and *see* the output.

Comment: btw one can guess but it is hard to fix the code and know its output when you only provide the broken version and dont know what it is supposed to print...

Comment: So here 0 is directly passed in the macro ,not as in like a variable. (Like in a function)

Comment: ..kind of.. macros dont know variables, they only know text, so what is "passed" to the macro is the string "0" and any occurence of the symbol `i` inside the marco is replaced by this string. Macros are not functions

Comment: Okay :) now it's clear

Comment: Don't use a macro to define something that is a functuion. Use inline function in C++ instead.

Comment: @VipulSinha you could try to do `int i = 0; PRINT(i,3);`, but still this is nothing you should do in real code

Comment: Even if it was a function and it would compile, it would still be very bad. I mean, that is not how you write a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After expanding the macro, `if(i++<LIMIT)` becomes `if (0++ < 3)` and `0++` is not an valid expression.

To make it work, you define a variable in your `main()` and pass that variable to the macro:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    PRINT(a, 3);
    return 0;
}
```

Note, the macro you defined is actually an infinite loop (at least for the parameters given). If you intend to print it for three times, you need

```
#define PRINT(i, LIMIT) \
do { \
    cout<<"Gradeup";\
}while(++i<LIMIT)
```

Comment: *"not an invalid expression"* - It is an invalid expression, actually. Or did you mean it's not a valid one? ;)

Comment: @StoryTeller, you are right. Sorry, that is a typo. As @mch pointed out, `0` is not an l-value and it cannot be increased.

Answer (score 0):

Just note that any identifier defined in a macro **is not a variable**. It's a "replacement identifier". So you don't have a variable named `i` but anything supplied to there.

Then your macro expands like this

```
PRINT(0, 3);
// Expand result
do{   if(0++<3)
...
```

The compiler surely is complaining about that `0++` is not a valid expression. 0 is an **Rvalue** and thus cannot be used with increment operators (which requires an Lvalue).